What is up with Yaakov and Rivka's tricks - couldn't they have just explained their situation to Yitzchak?
A majority of Parshas Toldos deals with Rivka and Yaakov tricking Yitzchak into giving Yaakov the Brachos. Yaakov dressed up like Eisav, he sort of lied by saying "I am, Eisav your son", (see Rashi there), and a few other tricky stuff.
One of our Avos and one of our Imahos just does stuff like this!?! They just trick people - this is very hard to understand! And if you will say that the Brachos were rightfully Yaakov's since he got the Bechora, then why didn't he just tell Yitzchak? Furthermore, after Yitzchak found out that he was tricked, he said that Yaakov should still be blessed, and Rashi explains that he approved what Yaakov did. Yitzchak said - "He cleverly took the Brachos."
So what is up with them tricking, or not explaining the situation to Yitzchak, and what is up with Yitzchak approving of this!?!

Arizal learns that Yitschak new Esav wasn't so good. And still wanted to bless him, for that would cause yakov and jews to repent. And Rivka argued and held hews cant handle that. There was no explaning to do. It was simply a machlokes

But why did they trick him?

Because he wouldn't have agreed to it..

@Shlomy - we still have the question. Yitzchok and Rvka had a disagreement, so she tricked him!?!

The future of all of clal yisrael was at stake.... You have a better option?
